# Ember.js computed property based on property from another model

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a project to display a list of top selling items based on the number of times they have been bought as a cloud. I am displaying the data using masonry from Ember.js and I want to display the items arranged as per the "numberItems" in 10 different div sizes - 1 to 10 based on the percentage of numberItems out of the total number of Items. (div size1 for 0-10% and so on).

```
{"clouds": [
    {"numberItems": 202, "itemName": "item1", "rank": 1, "id": 1},
    {"numberItems": 342, "itemName": "item2", "rank": 2, "id": 2}, 
    {"numberItems": 122, "itemName": "item3", "rank": 5, "id": 3}, 
    {"numberItems": 121, "itemName": "item4", "rank": 7, "id": 4}, 
    {"numberItems": 95, "itemName": "item5", "rank": 3, "id": 5}, 
    {"numberItems": 72, "itemName": "item6", "rank": 6, "id": 6}, 
    {"numberItems": 22, "itemName": "item7", "rank": 4, "id": 7}
]}
```

I get the total number of items as a part of the user profile which is in the following format.

```
{"userprofiles": [
    {"loggedIn": true, 
     "firstName": "Clark", 
     "totalItems": 1098, 
     "lastName": "Kent", 
     "id": "mail@clarkkent.com"}
]}
```

Now both these are fetched using DjangoRESTAdapter.

I have the following Ember.js code:

```
App.Userprofile = DS.Model.extend({
    loggedIn: DS.attr('boolean'),
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    totalItems: DS.attr('number'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName','lastName')
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('userprofile', 'mail@clarkkent.com');
    }
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.extend({

    host: HOST,
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

Now, from the above Model I need the totalItems property to calculate the size of the div in the Cloud model, and in which I am not able to refer the totalItems property properly. Here is the code for the same.

```
App.Cloud = DS.Model.extend({
    numberItems: DS.attr('number'),
    itemName: DS.attr('string'),
    rank: DS.attr('number'),
    divsize: function(value) {
        var that = this;
        value = null;
        this.store.find('userprofile', 'mail@clarkkent.com').then(function(model) {
            var ti = model.get('totalItems');
            console.log ("divsize is:" + value); // This gets run later than the outside console.log
            value = ti;
        });
        console.log ("divsize is:" + value); // This gets returned immediately and the page is rendered
        return "score4"; // I am returning a default value now
    }.property('numberItems')
});

App.CloudAdapter = DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.extend({

    host: HOST,
    namespace: 'api',
});

App.ItemcloudRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.findAll('cloud');
    }
});
```

Note the the data is properly being called and rendered and there is no issue there.

I feel there should be a very straightforward way to do it and not the way i am doing. Let me know if I should rephrase my question in some way. I know I can do the calculation on the server side and send out another field but that is just not elegant.

[Update]: Here is relevant portion of the template file:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='application'>
    {{totalItems}} Items for <strong>{{fullName}}</strong>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='itemcloud'>
    {{#each cloud in model}}
        <div {{bind-attr class=":company cloud.divsize"}}>
            <div class="companylogo">
                <img src="images/logos/color-logos/logo-01.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="count">{{cloud.numberItems}}</div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: how is cloud and userprofile actually related, beside the hard coded email addy?  Or is that analogous to the currently logged in user?

Comment: I have included the template as well. In this case userprofile is analogous to the logged in user and is rendered from the default application template. The itemcloud is rendered from {{outlet}} within the application template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using controllers. Here is the code:

```
App.CloudController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    divsize: function() {
        var dsize = Math.round (this.get('model.numberItems') * 10 / this.get('controllers.application.totalItems')) + 1;
        console.log ("size is: " + dsize);
        return "score" + dsize;
    }.property('model.numberItems', 'controllers.application.totalitems')
});
```